# How does SLF4J OSGi work given apparent mismatch in package versions?

Tags: osgi, slf4j

In all versions of SLF4J that I've looked at after 1.6.0, the slf4j-api MANIFEST.MF looks like (this is in 1.7.21):

```
Import-Package: org.slf4j.impl;version=1.6.0
```

But the backends (e.g. slf4j-log4j12) say:

```
Export-Package: org.slf4j.impl;version=1.7.21
```

This doesn't fit together, it leads to unresolved package wiring.

I know that lots of people use SLF4J in OSGi. Heck, *I* use it, and it works, but pax-logging may be obscuring the issue. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Import-Package: org.slf4j.impl;version=1.6.0
```

Specifying an exact version at Import-Package means version 1.6.0 or greater. Therefore this line does not cause an unresolved package.

However, all of the SLF4J implementation bundles need the API, too. By having this rule, we get a cyclic dependency. SLF4J guys solved this issue by making each implementation bundles as fragment bundles of the API.

In every implementation bundle you can see these:

```
Fragment-Host: slf4j.api
```

and

```
Import-Package: org.slf4j;version=1.7.21,...
```

Based on the MANIFEST headers: The implementation bundle must be at least version 1.6.0 and the API bundle version must be at least as big as the version of the implementation bundle.

Comment: Oh. I thought you needed [1.6.0, 2.0) to get 'at least'.

Comment: But now I know better.

Comment: From osgi-core spec: `A consumer of an API should therefore import a range that starts with the base version and ends
with the next major change, for example: [4.2,5). A provider of an API should import a range that
starts with the base version up to the next minor change, for example: [4.2,4.3).`. Also: `If a version range is specified as a single version, it must be interpreted as the range [version,∞).`

Comment: Also if you don't specify a version at all on your Import-Package, then the range `[0.0.0, infinity)` is inferred. In other words it will resolve to *any* version.